# Using SCNGeometryTessellator with a SCNGeometry that uses a custom SCNProgram?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, metal

I'm trying to add a `SCNGeometryTessellator` to some SceneKit geometry that uses a custom `SCNProgram`. My geometry renders fine normally, but as soon as I add the `SCNGeometryTessellator`, I see this error:

```
[SceneKit] Error: Compiler error while building render pipeline state for node <C3DNode:0x1053e9700 "(null)"
  geometry: <C3DParametricGeometry<Plane>:0x1053e9160 "(null)"
  mesh: <C3DMesh 0x282590620 "(null)"
  element0: <C3DMeshElement 0x2823922b0 type:triangles primCount:200 channels:1 indexBytes:2 offset:0 acmr:0.605000 inst:1 dataSize:1200 shared:0x0>
  source position (channel:0) : <C3DMeshSource 0x2837fbbf0(position) data:(0x281009ce0) mut:0 count:121 type:float3 divisor:0 mtl:0 offset:0 stride:32>
  source normal (channel:0) : <C3DMeshSource 0x2837fb480(normal) data:(0x281009ce0) mut:0 count:121 type:float3 divisor:0 mtl:0 offset:12 stride:32>
  source texcoord (channel:0) : <C3DMeshSource 0x2837fbb80(texcoord) data:(0x281009ce0) mut:0 count:121 type:float2 divisor:0 mtl:0 offset:24 stride:32>
  renderable element0: <C3DMeshElement 0x2823922b0 type:triangles primCount:200 channels:1 indexBytes:2 offset:0 acmr:0.605000 inst:1 dataSize:1200 shared:0x0>
  renderable source position: <C3DMeshSource 0x2837fbbf0(position) data:(0x281009ce0) mut:0 count:121 type:float3 divisor:0 mtl:0 offset:0 stride:32>
  renderable source normal: <C3DMeshSource 0x2837fb480(normal) data:(0x281009ce0) mut:0 count:121 type:float3 divisor:0 mtl:0 offset:12 stride:32>
  renderable source texcoord: <C3DMeshSource 0x2837fbb80(texcoord) data:(0x281009ce0) mut:0 count:121 type:float2 divisor:0 mtl:0 offset:24 stride:32>
>
  mat0: <C3DMaterial 0x2837159d0 : "(null)", custom <C3DFXTechnique>>
>
>:
Error Domain=AGXMetalA14 Code=3 "Attribute 0 incompatible with MTLStepFunctionPerPatchControlPoint." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Attribute 0 incompatible with MTLStepFunctionPerPatchControlPoint.}
[SceneKit] Error: _executeProgram - no pipeline state
```

Here's how I create my geometry:

```swift
let program = SCNProgram()
program.vertexFunctionName = "myVertexShader"
program.fragmentFunctionName = "myFragmentShader"

let mat = SCNMaterial()
mat.program = previewProgram

let plane = SCNPlane()
plane.widthSegmentCount = 1
plane.heightSegmentCount = 1
plane.firstMaterial = mat

let tessellator = SCNGeometryTessellator()
tessellator.edgeTessellationFactor = 10.0
tessellator.insideTessellationFactor = 10.0
tessellator.smoothingMode = .pnTriangles
plane.tessellator = tessellator

// add plane node to scene...
```

The tesselator actually works if I remove the custom material, but I need to use a SCNProgram.

What is causing this error and how can I use `SCNGeometryTessellator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you add a `tessellator` an `SCNGeometry`, your `SCNProgram` needs to use a post-tessellation vertex function instead of a standard vertex function. The only doc I've found that really covers this is Apple's [metal tessellation programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Tessellation/Tessellation.html)

While I'm not an expect on Metal tessellation, here's my understanding of the issue:

Let's say your normal vertex function looks something like this:

```
struct VertexInput {
    float3 position [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition)]];
    float3 normal [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticNormal)]];
    float2 texCoords [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticTexcoord0)]];
};

vertex ColorInOut myVertexShader(VertexInput in [[ stage_in ]], ...) {
    ...
}
```

The error about `Attribute 0 incompatible with MTLStepFunctionPerPatchControlPoint` is explaining that your input type (`VertexInput`) does not match the expected vertex input for the current render pipeline. This is because once you add tessellation, the render pipeline changes to use a special post tessellation vertex function instead of a standard vertex function.

A post tessellation vertex function takes input from the tessellator instead of from your geometry. Here's the above vertex shader converted to a post tessellation vertex function:

```
struct PatchIn {
    patch_control_point<VertexInput> control_points;
};

[[patch(triangle, 3)]]
vertex ColorInOut myVertexShader(PatchIn patchIn [[stage_in]],
                                 float3 patch_coord [[ position_in_patch ]], ...)
{
    // We have to compute the correct input positions from the tessellation data 
    // Note that there's probably a cleaner/better way to do this

    // Barycentric coordinates
    float u = patch_coord.x;
    float v = patch_coord.y;
    float w = patch_coord.z;
    
    // Convert to cartesian coordinates
    const float3 pos = float3(
                              u * patchIn.control_points[0].position.x + v * patchIn.control_points[1].position.x + w * patchIn.control_points[2].position.x,
                              u * patchIn.control_points[0].position.y + v * patchIn.control_points[1].position.y + w * patchIn.control_points[2].position.y,
                              u * patchIn.control_points[0].position.z + v * patchIn.control_points[1].position.z + w * patchIn.control_points[2].position.z);
    
    ...
}
```

After rewriting the vertex function to a post tessellation vertex function, your geometry should render with tessellation and your custom `SCNProgram`